# Swift/iOS - How to use a value from one scope/function and pass it into another?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to pass the value of gyroX to another function but it just ends up in it having a value of 0 when I use it as gyroX in that other function.

Here is the code:

```swift
var gyroX = Float()
        
motion.startGyroUpdates(to: .main) { (data, error) in
    if let myData = data {
        gyroX = Float(myData.rotationRate.x)
    }
}
```

Comment: The update closure is called asynchronously when the value updates (which will be very frequently).  You would be better to call the function that needs the value from the closure rather than trying to use the value outside the closure

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks.. I tried that but it was giving me errors.. I'll try it again though in case I missed something.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## With Xcode 13 Beta and Swift 5.5

This is a problem that we can now solve with Async/Await's Continuations

We would first make a function that converts the callback into an awaitable result like:

```swift
func getXRotation(from motion: CMMotionManager) async throws -> Float {
    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        class GyroUpdateFailure: Error {} // make error to throw
        motion.startGyroUpdates(to: .main) { (data, error) in
            if let myData = data {
                continuation.resume(returning:  Float(myData.rotationRate.x))
            } else {
                throw GyroUpdateFailure()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then we can assign the variable and use it like so:

```swift
let gyroX = try await getXRotation(from: motion)
callSomeOtherFunction(with: gyroX)
```

## With Xcode <= 12 and Combine

In the current release of Swift and Xcode we can use the Combine framework to make callback handling a little easier for us. First we'll convert the closure from the motion manager into a "Future". Then we can use that future in a combine chain.

```swift
func getXRotation(from motion: CMMotionManager) -> Future<CMGyroData, Error> {
    Future { promise in
        class GyroUpdateFailure: Error {} // make error to throw
        motion.startGyroUpdates(to: .main) { (data, error) in
            if let myData = data {
                promise(.success(myData))
            } else {
                promise(.failure(GyroUpdateFailure()))
            }
        }
    }
}

// This is the other function you want to call
func someOtherFunction(_ x: Float) {}

// Then we can use it like so
_ = getXRotation(from: motion)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    .map { Float($0.rotationRate.x) }
    .map(someOtherFunction)
    .sink { completion in
        switch completion {
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        default: break
        }
    } receiveValue: {
        print($0)
    }
```

There are some important parts to the combine flow. The `_ =` is one of them. The result of "sinking" on a publisher is a "cancellable" object. If we don't store that in a local variable the system can clean up the task before it fishes executing. So you will want to do that for sure.

I highly recommend you checkout SwiftBySundell.com to learn more about Combine or Async/Await and RayWenderlich.com for mobile development in general.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I'll see if I can get it to work. Much appreciated!

Comment: My pleasure! Let me know if you get hung up.

Comment: BTW with the xcode 12 solution, you'll need to add `import Combine` to the top of your file.

Comment: Ok, I put the Combine / XCode 12 way in there now and got it working... how would I use it outside of those functions?  For example I tried:  "print(getXRotation(from: motion))" and it gave me a "Combine.Future<__C.CMGyroData, Swift.Error>" output.

Comment: You get back a special kind of response that doesn't actually execute until `sink` is called. I would do it in the publisher chain like `.map { print($0); return $0 }` There may be a `.print()` function in combine... IDK though.

Comment: My pleasure. If this solved your issue, you can mark the answer as accepted and others will know you don't need help anymore.

Comment: Right on... I couldn't get the print to work... what I'm really trying to do though is multiply a var by the X Gyroscope values... would that have a different way of calling the value for that?

Comment: No, you would just do that in that chain of function calls. After you get the float value in the map, you can do another `.map { $0 * someFloat }`

Comment: Can you share all of the code you’re executing there so I can look at it? You could either add more to your question or make a gist and share the link. https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Ok, I created a gist for it here: https://gist.github.com/Jeromepullen/a8f6484540c146f6468834b78940a16d   .. the line that I am trying to multiply the gyroscope value with is on line 87 (              playSound(pitch: 2000 * (value of gyroscope X coordinate)))

Comment: If it helps at all I basically am trying to make an app like my other one that I will link to if you wanted to check it out that uses the gyroscope to manipulate the pitch and other audio effects.. I made that app using Unity however and now I am using Swift for this current one in order to record sound using the microphone and playing back whatever was recorded being manipulated by the gyroscope.. the Unity app that I already have out uses preloaded sound files of songs that I made and I would try to make this current one using Unity as well but I couldn't figure out how to record and..

Comment: playback the recording on iOS through using Unity .. anyways here is the app that I already have out: https://apps.apple.com/ee/app/gyro-cavves/id1565452128

Comment: the C# Unity code that I used for that was "m_AudioSource.pitch = Input.gyro.attitude.x * 2.5f;"  by the way which is a bit different than Swift (which you can prolly tell I'm a total noob to haha)

Comment: also the weird button names on this one are because I started this from a Udacity course (https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud585) which is how I got the recording and playback to work... I just took out all of the buttons except for one of them (the snailButton) .. I just wanted one that the user would press to start the playback of the sound

Comment: I took that udacity course a few years ago. It was a great course! I left some comments on your gist. I think that should do the trick.